# Constraining API Call / Fetch to once per day / usage - React Native

Tags: react-native, fetch, local-storage

I have searched everywhere and just cannot find an answer for this. What I want to do can be described as follows:

On a user's first time opening the application for a given day, make an API call. Store the API call in local storage, and then for the rest of the day, simply rely on the stored data in local storage (data comes from local storage as opposed to API call now).

However, once that full day passes, a new API call is made the next time the user opens the application and that data is used to update the data in local storage. Rinse and repeat. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: So how would it work if the user does not use the app the next day? Would the API call still be made or is it dependent on the user using the app again?

Comment: Dependent on user using the app again, so basically we take the maximum of either a full day or the period between user opening application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the date of when the last API call was made, for example, `lastAPIFetchDate`, then each time the app opens you compare `lastAPIFetchDate` with today's date and if the `lastAPIFetchDate` is before today's date, make the API call, if not, get the data from the storage.

Comment: Ahhhh. This makes a lot of sense and I'm honestly embarrassed to have not thought of that. This will take me a little bit to get around to adding but I will accept as an answer once I try it (and it should work).